# Wordpress & Zend Framework application working togheter?

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework

I have in my site a Wordpress running in the root directory, ie: mysite.com/

And I need to create a ZF Application, and host it under a subdirectory of my hosting, ie: mysite.com/backend

I did under my root directory:

% zf create project backend

It created the "backend" directory under my root, with all the project inside.

Under my root directory I have this .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Under webroot/backend/public I have this .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

I'm using ZF 1.11

What I can't figure how must I configure is the .htaccess files to get this zf app working under the subdirectory.

Regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to put this .htacess inside mysite.com/backend

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule !\.(csv|js|gif|jpg|png|css|txt)$ public/index.php [L]
```

And then in my Bootstrap.php this:

```
public function run() {
        $front   = $this->getResource('FrontController');
        $front->setBaseUrl('/backend');
}
```

So Zend can route the requests in the right way.

Answer (score 1):

Currently you have a folder backend . So it looks

mysite.com/backend

Now when you create project with

```
zf create project <project name>
```

you will be getting a directory structure . From that move the index.php and .htaccess ( from the public folder ) to the backend folder.

Upload all the remaining  folder to the one which is not accessible via web . ie below the web root directory ( public or what ever you call )

Change the APPLICATION_PATH in the index.php of the backend folder according to the where your project folder is now.

Its very easy with zend framework. Hope this will help you.

May be you want to look whether wordpress .htaccess will allow the directory which is already there .